# How does Ruby store large numbers?

Tags: ruby, binary, integer, 64-bit, largenumber

Ruby can store extremely large numbers. Now that I think about it though, I don't even know how that's possible.

Computers store data in a series of two digits (0s and 1s). This is referred to as binary notation. However, there is a limit to the size of numbers they can store.

Most current Operating Systems these days run at 64 bits. That means the highest allocatable address space for a variable is 64 bits.

Integers are stored in a base 2 system, which means the highest value a computer should be able to store is

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Since computers can only read 2 possible values, this means the above number can be represented as

```
2 ^ 64
```

This means that the highest value an integer can read should be at most 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

I honestly don't even understand how it's possible to store integer values higher than that.

Comment: You understand how to store binary files larger than 64 bytes in memory? Now imagine the file holds the binary value of a very large integer...

Comment: Simple, it doesnt' rely on just 64 bits. While I'm not going to get into the details (since I don't fully grok them) you want to take a look at BigNum and BigDecimal. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Bignum.html

Comment: How can you store large numbers with just 10 fingers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby uses [`Bignum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Bignum.html) objects to store number larger than `2^64`. You can see [here](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/1/9/how-big-is-a-bignum) a description of how this works:

> [image: class_diagram]
>
> On the left, you can see RBignum contains an inner structure called
>   RBasic, which contains internal, technical values used by all Ruby
>   objects. Below that I show values specific to Bignum objects: digits
>   and len. digits is a pointer to an array of 32-bit values that contain
>   the actual big integer’s bits grouped into sets of 32. len records how
>   many 32-bit groups are in the digits array. Since there can be any
>   number of groups in the digits array, Ruby can represent arbitrarily
>   large integers using RBignum.

Comment: Interesting explanation. I had heard about the Bignum class, and knew that Ruby could store extremely large numbers. But was unsure how it actually did that. Many thanks for the explanation.

Comment: So are they added together at a point if need be?  By that I mean the value of digits.  Also, are these arrays preset (as in those values all exist already for example 3040492174021840921480921480 and 21409824190842190489281) but in bitcode?  Like I think I understand but I guess they would be created as objects when they are created. The word that confused me I think was 'actual'